# Scala How to use pattern matching with a non generic LazyList?

Tags: scala, list, functional-programming, pattern-matching, lazy-evaluation

In Scala 2.13 I have encountered a problem with pattern matching using the operator `#::`, which displays error `Cannot resolve method #::.unapply` when used as follows:

```
def exampleFunction(lazyList: LazyList[Int]):Unit =
  lazyList match {
    case LazyList() => println("End")
    case head #:: tail => println(head); exampleFunction(tail) // Cannot resolve method #::.unapply
  }
exampleFunction(LazyList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
```

---

When the LazyList is generic, the operator does work as expected:

```
def exampleFunction[A](lazyList: LazyList[A]):Unit =
  lazyList match {
    case LazyList() => println("End")
    case head #:: tail => println(head); exampleFunction(tail)
  }
exampleFunction(LazyList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)) // output: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 End
```

---

Why does this problem occur and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Your first snippet version appears to compile fine, see https://scastie.scala-lang.org/iab8q5EdS0qV20xLwY4J0Q

Comment: I cannot seem to replicate the issue on my machine. Try with `import scala.collection.immutable.LazyList.#::`

Comment: Adding `import scala.collection.immutable.LazyList.#::` fixed the problem completely and everything now works, thank you!

Comment: @kamnov . I also faced the same issue and adding the import solved the issue. How ever I am not sure why we need to add the import explicitly in case of LazyList, when this is not applicable in case of List.
Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: @MarioGalic you should put an answer with your comment, it also fixed this issue for me. I also don't understand why this is needed.

Comment: @jrod Are you using IntelliJ?

Comment: @MarioGalic yes, IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3 Community edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you are using IntelliJ, this might be due to in-editor error highlighting bug [SCL-15834: Highlighting error on case matching using operator #::](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-15834) In other words, this is a false positive where the code compiles successfully however IntelliJ's [custom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61099741/how-to-configure-intellij-scala-plugin-to-use-scalas-native-presentation-compil) error highlighting process incorrectly identifies a problem. Providing explicit import

```
import scala.collection.immutable.LazyList.#::
```

seems to make the editor error highlighting happy, however the import should not be necessary. Few other suggestion to try

- `File | Invlidate Caches`
- From the root of the project `rm -fr .idea` and then re-import project
- Update to bleeding edge Scala Plugin version: `Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Scala | Updates | Update channel | Nightly Builds`
- Within `Registry...` enable experimental flag `scala.highlighting.compiler.errors.in.editor`